# Mysql query and php (loop) to get corresponding values

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have a table contain `pID` values and `amount` values,

```
|   pID     |   amount  |   date        |
|    1      |    20     |   2014-10-1   |
|    1      |    30     |   2014-12-30  |
|    2      |    40     |   2014-10-10  |
|    2      |     3     |   2014-12-01  |
```

I want to use both mysql query and php (loop) to get a `pID` corresponding with its `amount` for just one `pID` for different rows,

Below is how I want my answer to be in

For `queryAns 1` I select data from `2014-10-1` to `2014-10-30`

```
queryAns 1
|   pID     |   amount  |
|    1      |      20   |
|    2      |      40   |
```

For `queryAns 2` I select data from `2014-12-1` to `2014-12-30`

```
queryAns 2
|   pID     |   amount  |
|    1      |      30   |
|    2      |       3   |
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry guys, i guess i missed the date in the `maintable`
The condition will be based on a particular month and year.
I would also wish to query the data based on a date range, for instance selecting data from 
2014-10-1 to 2014-10-10

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the condition, to group by? e.g. how do I know which ones are in the first or second answer?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, I have updated my question, i missed the date which is the condition. Thanks

Comment: is it possible to group by month and year, or possibly group by date range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do your select like this:

```
SELECT
 maintable.pID,
 maintable.amount,
 DATE_FORMAT(maintable.date, '%Y-%m') as date
FROM
 maintable
WHERE
 maintable.date BETWEEN '2014-10-01' AND '2014-10-10'
 OR maintable.date BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-05'
GROUP BY
 YEAR(maintable.date), MONTH(maintable.date)
```

Comment: thanks, but please is it possible to group by date range

Comment: @George could you please explain this in your question above?

Comment: Yeah i have explained that in my question

Comment: please make an example for a date range, what should the result look like? and how does the range look like?

Comment: @George I'm not sure if you have seen my updated answer with the range. please have a look there.

Comment: Muller, thanks I have checked.Thanks for your time. Really appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68922/discussion-between-george-and-raphael-muller).

Answer (score 0):

You first query should look alike:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum
       FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, mainTable
     ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % n = 1;
```

And the second one should look alike:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum
       FROM ( SELECT @row :=0) r, mainTable
     ) ranked 
WHERE rownum % n = 0;
```

Comment: Would be possible to get only one query to this.